# Error calling a subclass method from another class

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have three classes:

```
public class BikeSystem {

    static Bicycle[] bicycleArray = new Bicycle[100];
    static int currentBikes = 0;

    public static void addUnicycle() {

        bicycleArray[currentBikes] = new Unicycle();
        currentBikes++; 
    }

    public static void addUniWheel() {
        for (int i=0; i < currentBikes; i++) {
            if (bicycleArray[i] instanceof Unicycle)
                bicycleArray[i].addWheel();
        }
     }
}

public class Bicycle {

    // some variables

}

public class Unicycle extends Bicycle {

    private int wheels;

    public boolean addWheel() {
        wheels++;
        return true;
    }


}
```

However, I keep getting a "cannot find symbol" error when I try to call the `bicycleArray[i].addWheel()` method in my BikeSystem class. How do I get around this?

Comment: Having a `Unicycle` with more than one wheel makes it something other than a unicycle does it not?

Answer (score 1):

You should explicitly state that you are operating on an instance of `Unicycle` in order to gain access to the `addWheel()` method. You can do this by casting.

```
((Unicycle) bicycleArray[i]).addWheel();
```

Obviously, if you try to cast to `Unicycle` on an instance of an object that is not a `Unicycle` or a further subclass, you will get a `ClassCastException`

Answer (score 1):

`bicycleArray` is declared as an array of `Bicycle` and there is no `addWheel` method defined by it.

You're trying something similar as:

```
Bicycle bicycle = new Bicycle();
bicycle = new Unicycle();
bicycle.addWheel(); // err
```